Preserving an immutable variable required at a higher scope while an error is raised
I have set up a worker application in Python. As part of this worker, I always require a new_process_time to be defined in the return, such that the external queue can handle it properly.
Sometimes a severe error type may occur, which should abort the handling of this iteration entirely. This is undesired, but expected. In this case a default time is picked as the return.
My issue occurs when the abort-worthy error occurs, after the next new_process_time has already been found. Ideally, I'd want to both raise and log this error, while simultaneously retaining new_process_time to be handed to the queue, instead of a default.
I can think of 2 implementations:

Catch the error, return it alongside the var, and reraise it, aborting the wider worker context:
def foo(new_process_time):
    condition = True
    e = None
    try:
        new_process_time = 10  # Calculated within foo() through context only available in foo()
        if condition:
            raise ValueError("Stuff broke.")
        ...  # logic I wish to abort if an exception is raised
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Error triggered')
        return new_process_time, e
    return new_process_time, e


def worker():
    new_process_time = None
    try:
        new_process_time, e = foo(new_process_time)
        if e is not None:
            raise e
        ...  # logic I wish to abort if an exception is raised
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Logging the exception: {e}")
    finally:
        if new_process_time is not None:
            print(f"Next schedule: {new_process_time}")
        else:
            print(f"Next schedule: DEFAULT")

worker()


Use a generator:
def foo_2(new_process_time):
    condition = True
    try:
        new_process_time = 10  # Calculated within foo() through context only available in foo()
        yield new_process_time
        if condition:
            raise ValueError("Stuff broke.")
        ...  # logic I wish to abort if an exception is raised
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Error triggered')
        raise e


def worker_2():
    new_process_time = None
    try:
        try:
            foo_gen = foo_2(new_process_time)
            new_process_time = next(foo_gen)  # handle the logic up to new_process_time
            next(foo_gen)  # handle the rest of the logic
        except StopIteration:
            print('this is fine, continue as normal')
        ...  # logic I wish to abort if an exception is raised
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Logging the exception: {e}")
    finally:
        if new_process_time is not None:
            print(f"Next schedule: {new_process_time}")
        else:
            print(f"Next schedule: DEFAULT")

worker_2()



I am not a fan of either of these implementations. While they both work, I feel they (the generator option more than the return) are unpythonic and contain anti-patterns. Simply put, asking for trouble.
Alternatively, I reckon global might be an option here, but given the many reasons to avoid it. I imagine when the worker function is ran in parallel, this would cause problems.
How to ensure a variable required at a higher scope, but prevented from returning normally due to an error that must be raised, is still accessible?

Put the immutable variable into a mutable box:
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class TimeContext:
    new_process_time: int | None = None

Then foo does not need to care about the errors
def foo(time_context: TimeContext):
    condition = True

    time_context.new_process_time = 10  # this is reflected in the outer function
    if condition:
        raise ValueError("Stuff broke.")

And worker does not have to unwrap the errors:
def worker():
    time_context = TimeContext()
    try:
        foo(time_context)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Logging the exception: {e}")
    finally:
        if time_context.new_process_time is not None:
            print(f"Next schedule: {time_context.new_process_time}")
        else:
            print(f"Next schedule: DEFAULT")


I guess my question really comes down to 'datatype is immutable, what now?' the answer being as simple as 'make it mutable' is amazing. Let me test it in my wider implementation to confirm it works.
